# Why are my props undefined when I use a Route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm confused when re-passing props to children (particularly when inside a `Route`). For example:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.sayHi = this.sayHi.bind(this);
    }

    sayHi() {
        console.log('hi')
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <Router>
            <Route path="/projects" component={(props, state, params) => 
              <ProjectList 
                sayHi={this.sayHi}
              {...props} />} 
            />
          </Router>
        )
    }
}

const ProjectList = (props) => {
    return (
        <Route path={`${props.match.url}/:id`} component={(props, state, params) => 
          <ProjectDetail 
            sayHi={props.sayHi}
          {...props} />} 
        />
    )
}

const ProjectDetail = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
}
```

Within the `ProjectList` component, I have no problem accessing the `sayHi` method (I can attach it to an `onClick` event within this component), but in the `ProjectDetail` component, I get an undefined for `props.sayHi`.

How am I incorrectly passing this prop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've just a problem with parameters of the same name. In your `ProjectList` component:

```
<Route path={`${props.match.url}/:id`} component={(props, state, params) => 
    <ProjectDetail 
         sayHi={props.sayHi}
    {...props} />} 
/>
```

When you are creating a `ProjectDetail` element and pass the `sayHi` prop, you have to access *`ProjectList`'s props*, not the props of the arrow function (the props [`Route` passes](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/Route-props)). The parameters are "overriding" each other because they are under the same name, `props`. So, try:

```
const ProjectList = (props) => {
    return (
        <Route path={`${props.match.url}/:id`} component={(routeProps, state, params) => // use name "routeProps" instead of "props"
            <ProjectDetail 
                sayHi={props.sayHi}
            {...props} />} 
        />
    )
}
```

We rename the `props` in the `component` prop's arrow function to `routeProps` which will get rid of the name conflict. This way, the props of `ProjectList` are passed to `ProjectDetail`, not the props that `Route` passes.